# Can a JApplet Listen on a Port and Write on an other one?

Tags: java, tomcat, port, japplet

Allright here is my problem I am currently devlopping a JApplet and a Application. Basicaly when the machine will start the Application will launch and you wont be able to see anything else. on the same machine a Appache Tomcat Server will be running to give access to the JApplet via the network. So the JApplet isn't necessarily there at all time. So i was wondering if it was possible for the Application to listen to a given port, so that when the JApplet comes online it would say on the port like "hey i am online do something about it!". Also is it possible for the Application to talk back to the JApplet on a port. So that they can both talk to each other.

If this is not clear I can make a Diagram to clarify the needs but basicaly is it possible for them to talk to each other? If they can, How do they do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An applet can connect to and listen on any port as long as it's signed.

See what applets can or can't do:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

Comment: Thank you for the response i was wondering if u knew anyway to make the chat to each other. thank you !

Comment: I don't know all your requirements, but it could be as simple as sending an UDP packet or opening a TCP connection. It could also be done by writing a file on the disk that the application would look for.

Comment: Well they are just gonna send string to each others so its a pretty basic connection i guess.. its the first time i am trying to do this so i have no clue how to do it :/

Comment: There are many examples on the net. Here is one the from the Java tutorial on the Oracle site: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: @emm maybe that advice should be an answer.